# How to extend request with type IncomingMessage

Tags: node.js, typescript, http

I'm trying to add property body to request:

```
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from "http";

interface IRequest extends IncomingMessage {
  body: string;
}
export default (request: IncomingMessage, response: ServerResponse, next: (req: IncomingMessage, res: ServerResponse) => void) => {
    let data: Uint8Array[] = []
    request.on("data", dataChunk => {
        data.push(dataChunk)
    })
    request.on("end", () => {
        const body = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
        if (request.headers["content-type"] === "application/json"){
          const extRequest: IRequest = {...request};
          extRequest.body = body;
          next(extRequest, response)
        }
    })
    request.on("error", () => {
      response.statusCode = 500;
      response.write(`body isn't correct`);
      response.end();
    })
}
```

But I have an error, that I don't have at my new object extRequest 19 functions from request. How to clone the whole object request?

Answer (score 0):

If you use this middleware with express, you should try to instead type the request/response with

`import { Request, Response } from 'express'`

so your code becomes:

```
import { Request, Response } from 'express';

 interface IRequest extends Request {
  body: string;
 }

export default (request: Request, response: Response, next: (req: Request, res: Response) => void) => {
    let data: Uint8Array[] = []
    request.on("data", dataChunk => {
        data.push(dataChunk)
    })
    request.on("end", () => {
        const body = Buffer.concat(data).toString();
        if (request.headers["content-type"] === "application/json"){
          const extRequest: IRequest = {...request};
          extRequest.body = body;
          next(extRequest, response)
        }
    })
    request.on("error", () => {
      response.statusCode = 500;
      response.write(`body isn't correct`);
      response.end();
    })
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't use express, the task is to implement server with only nodejs

Comment: @oksana where do you pass the function to?